# Generic method for HTTP GET/POST parameter conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I just made a method that should handle GET and POST parameters (primitive types) sent by AJAX requests to the server:

```
protected T GetParam<T>(string key) 
{
    string value = HttpContext.Current.Request[key];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return default(T);

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

Do you have any suggestions regarding improvements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First point, small but important: give your method a proper name. `GetParam` doesn't mean much and doesn't tell what it returns. Take a name like `GetValueFromParameter` or `GetHttpRequestValue`.

Secondly, did you test this method properly? I changed the code a bit to be able to test it, I removed the `HttpContext` value and just use the parameter as value:

```
protected T GetHttpRequestValue<T>(string value) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return default(T);

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

When I call it like this:

```
var longFromString = GetHttpRequestValue<long?>("0");
```

I get following exception:

> Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.

I went looking for a cause and it seems that `Convert.ChangeType` has problems with nullable types. You have to use the underlying type of the nullable in order to make it work:

```
protected T GetHttpRequestValue<T>(string key) 
{
    string value = HttpContext.Current.Request[key];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return default(T);

    var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T);
    var convertedValue = (value == null) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
    return (T)convertedValue ;
}
```

Now I get following results:

```
GetHttpRequestValue<long?>("0");    // 0
GetHttpRequestValue<long?>("");     // null
GetHttpRequestValue<long>("1");     // 1
GetHttpRequestValue<bool>("true");  // True
GetHttpRequestValue<bool>("");      // False

GetHttpRequestValue<long?>(null);   //null
GetHttpRequestValue<bool>(null);    //False
```

You also made your method dependent of an `HttpContext`, you cannot reuse it. Better would be to rename it to something like `ConvertTo` and leave out the `HttpContext`-line:

```
protected T ConvertTo<T>(string value) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return default(T);

    var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T);
    var convertedValue = (value == null) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
    return (T)convertedValue;
}
```

Example usage:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    var value = HttpContext.Current.Request["YourKey"];
    var converted = ConvertTo<long?>(value);
}
```

Your code is still clean and the method is reusable. Notice that I use `var` instead of explicitly declaring variables. This is not mandatory, I just prefer to use it. Hope this helps!

**Update:**

I updated the method to handle a fail on the conversion, in case you want to change `qwerty` to a `bool` for example. :)

```
protected T ConvertTo<T>(string value) 
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return default(T);

    var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T);
    T convertedValue = default(T);

    try
    {
        convertedValue = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
    }
    catch {}

    return convertedValue ;
}
```

This way of working swallows the exception. In case one occurs the default of `T` will be returned, otherwise the converted value. Results:

```
ConvertTo<int>("qwerty");    //0
ConvertTo<bool>("qwerty");   //False
```

**Update:**

As stated in the comments below, you can also take the code and throw it in an extension method. Also nice for reusability and your could will also look a bit cleaner. Here goes:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T ConvertTo<T>(this string value) 
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return default(T);

        var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T);
        T convertedValue = default(T);

        try
        {
            convertedValue = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
        }
        catch {}

        return convertedValue ;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var intFromString = "2".ConvertTo<int>();
//intFromString is an integer with value 2
```

Comment: Oooh, looks like I didn't test it good enough. Thanks for your input - much appreciated! I noticed that my example use was wrong. Obviously I intended to pass the request key and not the value, just as you spotted...

Comment: Another note is that `convertedValue` will never be null in the `ConvertTo` method

Comment: @Johan if the parameter `value` is *null* or empty, *null* will be returned. Otherwise there will be a conversion to the desired type. Note that an exception will occur when the conversion fails, for example "qwerty" as a bool.

Comment: @Johan I updated my answer for more information.

Comment: Yeah, my point is that `string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)` will catch the potential `null` value. Thus, `(value == null)` is unreachable when `value` is `null` and the statement can be simplfied: `var convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, type);`.

Comment: @Johan You're right about that, that's why I omitted it in the update with the *try/catch*.

Comment: Ah ok. I'll see if I can make a solution without resorting to try-catch. Thanks for your input once again!

Comment: I'm smelling extension method potential here...

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer loved your comment, I was thinking the same. I updated my answe. :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks good but not perfect IMHO.

- you should use braces `{}` for single `if` statements also. This is just a matter of taste, but I prefer the use of it as it makes the code less errorprone.
- The name of this method does not reflect what is happening. The code retrieves a value **not** a parameter, so a better name would be `GetValue`.